# how to enable birt logging in spring sts

Tags: eclipse, spring, birt

I am trying to write a report with sql parameters using the BIRT report designer in Eclipse. I'm getting an error which has to do with preparing the statement for the values.

How can I enable logging in Eclipse so I can look at the error in more detail?

I am using spring sts and I have set ...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_LOG_LEVEL</param-name>
    <param-value>FINEST</param-value>
</context-param>
```

inside ...

```
C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_3.7.2.v20120213\birt\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

But I'm still not getting any logs in the birt logs. I did a restart of spring sts after the changes.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

BIRT uses the java util logging, but you can write a simple log handler redirecting to log4j.
[view this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Q%3a_Can_I_use_Log4j_with_BIRT.3F) it shows how to use log4j in BIRT